# How to make awk respect the field separator?

Tags: awk, gawk

everyone

I pass a line to awk with *commas* as field separator. I'd like awk to produce the output still using commas as separator. However awk changes commas to spaces.

```
echo "qwer,asdf,zxcv" | awk -F',' '{gsub("a","b",$2); print $0}'
qwer bsdf zxcv
```

Is there a way to make awk respect the separator character of the original input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `OFS`, that is, Output Field Separator:

```
$ echo "qwer,asdf,zxcv" | awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{gsub("a","b",$2); print $0}'
qwer,bsdf,zxcv
```

---

Note also that `{print $0}` can be skipped and `-F` also included in the `BEGIN{}` block:

```
$ echo "qwer,asdf,zxcv" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub("a","b",$2)} 1'
qwer,bsdf,zxcv
```

Giving a `1` we give a True condition that is evaluated as `{print $0}` as default.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this with `awk`

```
echo "qwer,asdf,zxcv" | awk -F, '{gsub("a","b",$2); print $0}' OFS=,
qwer,bsdf,zxcv
```